# How to user single alias name for 2 columns at a time

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to use single alias name in mysql for two columns at a time

```
first_name, lname as username
```

In username, i want values of both first_name & lname

thanx in advance

Comment: like `CONCAT(first_name, '', lname) AS username` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in php as `CONCAT()`

In your case you can use as,

```
CONCAT(first_name, ' ', lname) as username
```

Comment: You wanted answer in PHP??

Answer (score 1):

Try to Concat fields
SELECT CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `lname`) as username FROM `table`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONCAT()` function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

```
CONCAT(first_name, ' ', lname) as username
```